# How to count the nested list elements size using Java 7?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-7

I have a Object which contains a list of another object which contains a list of another object and so on... suppose I want to get count of nested list elements(lets say last one), what should be best approach rather than using traditional for loop in java as I have done in below example -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Statement statement = new Statement();
    statement.getInvAccount().add(new InvestmentAccount());
    statement.getInvAccount().get(0).getSecAccountStmt().add(new SecurityStatement());
    statement.getInvAccount().get(0).getSecAccountStmt().get(0).getTransactionStatement().add(new TransactionStatement());
    statement.getInvAccount().get(0).getSecAccountStmt().get(0).getTransactionStatement().add(new TransactionStatement());
    statement.getInvAccount().get(0).getSecAccountStmt().get(0).getTransactionStatement().add(new TransactionStatement());

    // method to count the number of TransactionStatement
    System.out.println("Size of TransactionStatement is : " + count(statement));

}

private static int count(Statement stmt) {
    int countOfTransStmt = 0;
    for (InvestmentAccount invAcc : stmt.getInvAccount()) {
        if (invAcc != null) {
            for (SecurityStatement secStmt : invAcc.getSecAccountStmt()) {
                if (secStmt != null) {
                    countOfTransStmt = countOfTransStmt + secStmt.getTransactionStatement().size();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return countOfTransStmt;
}
```

Comment: I would go for a BFS kind of approach using queue. This way you can get hold of possible objects and inside the loop, you can easily find if that is of nested type or not as well. Let me know data sample to give any code example here.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the visitor pattern.

Comment: @JohnKugelman the level of nestedness is unknown

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes what if level of nestedness is more for example 6-7 ?

Comment: @JohnKugelman OP mentioned that "I have a Object which contains a list of another object which contains a list of another object and **so on...**"

Comment: @JohnKugelman Apologies , in real nested levels are 6, I just added quick example of 3 levels here.

Comment: Having 6-7 nested lists raises a lot of questions, such as "Are you modeling things properly?" and "Why do you need to loop over some deeply nested lists from so high up?" I strongly suspect an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Rather than jump to something complicated like visitors I'd first examine the framing of the problem. Maybe you're trying to do something unnatural, unnecessary, or that can be better accomplished by restructuring your data.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 7 you're not going to do better than two `for` loops. I wouldn't bother with anything different.

In Java 8 you can use streams to flatten it out:

```
private static int count(Statement stmt) {
    return stmt.getInvAccount().stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(InvestmentAccount::getSecAccountStmt)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(SecurityStatement::getTransactionStatement)
        .count();
}
```

I would encourage you to get rid of the null checks. If you're going to ignore nulls, better to just expect them not to be inserted in the first place. It'll get rid of a lot of extra `if` checks throughout your code, I expect.

I'd also encourage you not to abbreviate your variables and methods. Spell out "statement" and "investment" and the like. The abbreviations are harder to read and the brevity isn't really a win.

Similarly, try to use more descriptive method names. `countTransactions` is better for the main method. And for the various getters, methods that return lists ought to be plural: "getAccounts" rather than "getAccount". Notice how the getters now match the class names; if you know the class name, you know the getter name. You don't have to guess if one or the other is abbreviated:

```
private static int countTransactions(Statement statement) {
    return statement.getInvestmentAccounts().stream()
        .flatMap(InvestmentAccount::getSecurityStatements)
        .flatMap(SecurityStatement::getTransactionStatements)
        .count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, I am still using java 7, any suggestions to do this in java 7. Also null values might be there as I am getting this information from somewhere else on which do not have control.

Comment: IMHO, without Java 8+ you cannot escape the loops. Further more, if your code works your question is more suitable for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Hars Please put that Java 7 limitation in the question since Java 8 is the standard, not to mention that tomorrow will be official release of Java 11.

Comment: @John : Thanks for method naming suggestions, It was just a quick example for this post so names are not accurate. Also in real data I have 6 nested lists so I will be using around 5 for loops, will that be ok?

Answer (score -1):

Recursion could work in this case: 
General idea below:

```
 private int countTransactions(object t)
{
int sum = 0;
if (t == null) return 0;
for (int i = 0; i < t.getAllSub().count; i++)
{
    sum += countTransactions(t.subAt(i));
}

 return sum;
}
```

Comment: It won't work. The classes have different methods for accessing the inner lists.

Comment: It's possible the user could change the methods or add a wrapper method...